# Unknown "ckeditor_widget" function

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony-sonata, sonata

After update all my bundle with composer i'm have this error:

> Unknown "ckeditor_widget" function. Did you mean "ckeditor_plugin" in
>   "SonataFormatterBundle:Form:formatter.html.twig" at line 58?

i think there is a problem with SonataFormatterBundle

this is my composer.json

```
"require": { 
"php": ">=5.3.9", 
"symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
"egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "~2.2",
"sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "dev-master",
"sonata-project/page-bundle": "dev-master"
```

This is the line 58 in "SonataFormatterBundle:Form:formatter.html.twig" :

```
{{ source_id }}_rich_instance = {{
                        ckeditor_widget(form.children[source_field].vars.id, ckeditor_configuration)
                    }};
```

Any idea how how to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

it's seems like there is a problem with the dev-master version of ckeditor-bundle. so i downgrade from  "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "dev-master", to "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "3.0", and it works perfectly.